# How do we clear the icon in SwiftUI Pickers when switching from Label content to Text?

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, is a mix of Label and Text Views supported as the contents of a Picker? I'm seeing some visual glitches around the icon that suggests it is not.

In the example below, the picker initially appears correctly.

[image: Initial State - OK.]

Selecting "First Item" works as expected.

[image: Changed - Still OK.]

But reverting to the original state, by selecting "None", results in a label that still retains a phantom icon from the previous selection.

[image: Reverted - Not OK.]

Can anyone suggest a good workaround, if this is a bug? I tried using a label with an empty string for the systemImage (`Label("None", systemImage: "").tag(0)`). I also tried using a Label instead of the text, but without icon (`Label("None", systemImage: "house").labelStyle(.titleOnly).tag(0)`). In both cases the phantom icon was still there.

Here is the full code to illustrate the problem:

```swift
struct LabelAndTextInPicker: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Choice", selection: $selection) {
                Text("None").tag(0)
                Label("First Item", systemImage: "1.circle").tag(1)
                Label("Second Item", systemImage: "2.circle").tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like a bug. As a workaround try this, works for me:

```
            Label {
                Text("None")
            } icon: {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage())
            }.tag(0)
```

Comment: That works for me, too! Thanks for the confirmation and the workaround!